# How to search and replace an unprintable character

Tags: vim

I've a file that was exported from Word and it replaced all quotes with strange unicode characters which aren't correctly displayed in vim. 
So now I want those characters to be replaced with quotes, but I don't know how to enter this character in

```
:%s/???/'/g
```

The characters look like this: ~U  ~R. But of course I can't just mark them with mouse and paste in the command.

Comment: not programming related, belongs on superuser.com .

Comment: @ax: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: You can change all the "smart quotes" from Word documents (which are coded with a Microsoft propriatary coding scheme incompatible with utf-8 and iso-8859-15) with this command: [return]
`:%s/\%x92/'/g` [return]
Note there is no hidden character in this line.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can try setting the encoding type and see if it fixes the visalizations of those characters:

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

then you can use them directly. Alternatively, you can place your cursor on the unprintable character and hit `ga`, it will show the decimal/hex/octal code of that character, then you can substitute it with:

```
:%s/\%xYY/substitute/g
```

where `YY` is the hex code of the char, if it's multibyte:

```
:%s/\%uYYYY/substitute/g
```

for details:

```
:help character-classes
```

Note that you can search and match with `\%xff` or `\%uabcd` but will be [unable to substitute](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10089) with it.

Comment: Strangely, `/\%x00` didn't find anything, though "common" printables, like `/\%x41` did. To get the null value, I had to [use this trick](http://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-this-symbol-with-vim).

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `:set fileencoding=utf-8` instead? It does something quite different from `:set encoding=utf-8`.

Answer (score 7):

I usually:

1. delete the character with: `x`
2. undo my change with: `u`
3. do the substitute thanks to *c_CTRL-R*: `:%s/^R"/'/g`

Comment: Equivalently, you can also do `y` followed by space instead of `xu`, but whichever works for you.

Comment: Thanks Al! I've always wondered how to do this without a `vy` or a `xu`

Comment: Also `yl` (`l` is for letter).  And also `y<right>`, but that one is kind of awkward.

Answer (score 2):

you can also filter it by using the tr command

for example replacing the hex a0 which stems from MacOs cut-and-paste
can be replaced with a whitespace as follows (\240 being the octal representation of hex a0)

```
:.,$!tr "\240" " "
```