# removal hexcode in linux file

Tags: shell, vim, awk, sed, encoding

We receive a file with a lot of <96> today:

```
A^Y^ABC^EFG^HIJK<96>this - PM^0^0^0^456^-123^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^08/10/18
```

We would like to correct it into:

```
A^Y^ABC^EFG^HIJK^this - PM^0^0^0^456^-123^0^0^0^0^0^0^0^08/10/18
```

I did this in vi, but it says pattern not found:

```
:%s/<96>/^/g
```

I tried this

```
od -c file.txt
```

and return:

```
0000000   A   ^   Y   ^   A   B  C   ^   E   F    G
0000020   ^   H   I   J   K   <   9   6   >   t   h   i    
0000040   s       -       P
0000060   M   ^   0   ^   0   ^   0   ^   4   6   6   ^   -   1   2   3
0000100   ^   0   ^   0   ^   0   ^   0   ^   0   ^   0   ^   0   ^   0
0000120   8   /   1   0   /   1   8  \n
```

which does suggest <96> is <96>.  Don't know why I cannot replace <96> in vi.  Also I am curious what <96> means here? Any guru could help?  Thank you!

Comment: You might get more `vim` gurus looking if you tagged as such.

Comment: Is `file.txt` the one you originally tried to edit in vim? The `od` output contradicts your `vim` experience, so please make sure to use the same file. Specifically, do not attempt to copy-paste the data.

Comment: Agreed with @thatotherguy: if you have a literal four-character `<96>` in the file, the vim substitution you have in your question should have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace hex character 96 in Vim with:

```
:%s/\%x96/^/g
```

Here's `:help regex`:

```
                            /\%d /\%x /\%o /\%u /\%U E678

\%d123  Matches the character specified with a decimal number.  Must be
        followed by a non-digit.
\%o40   Matches the character specified with an octal number up to 0377.
        Numbers below 040 must be followed by a non-octal digit or a non-digit.
\%x2a   Matches the character specified with up to two hexadecimal characters.
\%u20AC Matches the character specified with up to four hexadecimal
        characters.
\%U1234abcd     Matches the character specified with up to eight hexadecimal
        characters.
```

In a script, you can replace it by its octal equivalent with `tr`:

```
LC_ALL=C tr '\226' '^'  <myfile.txt  >newfile.txt
```

Comment: You can also use `<C-v>` to enter characters such as this

Answer (score 1):

(mostly drawn from [How to search and replace an unprintable character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798398/how-to-search-and-replace-an-unprintable-character), read it for more advice)

If you want to find and replace an unprintable character, move your cursor onto it and press
`ga`
This will show the hex value of the character on the bottom of the screen.

to find and replace that hex character, run
`:%s/\%x[Hex]/[Replacement]/g`
where  `[Hex]` is the 2 digit hex code you found and `[replacement]` is whatever you want instead.

If the hex code is 4 digits, run this instead
`:%s/\%u[Hex]/[Replacement]/g`